# Feature request: Two step verification

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, security

Securing our digital accounts is a very important thing to do to be safe in the Internet. Having a strong password is just the start in my opinion. Two-step verification is a very important tool to keep our accounts safe. Many companies provide two-step verification feature to its users like Google, Apple, Microsoft, Amazon, etc.

I'm proposing  a two-step verification [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

If any of you feel this is not a necessary feature, let me know your reasons.

Comment: This was [proposed before in 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318807/2fa-for-stack-exchange-universal-login) but not deemed a priority. But that's 2 years ago, maybe they would give it priority now.